# Installed #! Linux with encryption; computer no longer boots

Tags: linux, boot, encryption, grub, post

I am rather stumped as to what to do at this point.

I installed #! Linux with the encryption option (using whole disk).  Afterwards it installed grub as well.  The computer no longer boots at all (see http://videobam.com/tPqOB -- I try a regular boot then try to boot it off another linux DVD in this video with the same result both times ).  I also get a clicking sound now (can't hear in video?).  I have done the same installation on two other computers (one x64, other x86) with no problems.  I also had #! on this computer to begin with, although not encrypted.

The weird thing is that it doesn't seem to even get into the POST ([picture](http://postimg.org/image/nwc8k4ger/)).  It just sits at this point.

The computer is somewhat old (2005?).  It is a Toshiba Satellite U205-S5057.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure your POSTING (I suspect thats happening behind the splash screen before the network boot attempt).  Have you tried holding down the escape key as you boot the system then press F1 when you get the check system message ?

It seems to me (but of-course, I don't have one of these PC's) that while reinstalling GRUB you managed to kill the contents of the boot sector of the disk - thus the computer is unable to find a boot image on the disk so it moves on to the next device to try and boot from it - ie the network card.

If you can boot into the BIOS maybe you can set it to boot off a USB key, and then either use that to repair your installation or do a new install ?

Comment: It looks like I didn't need to use a USB drive to do it.  I pressed escape during the splash screen and turned on WOL and then I was able to load my DVD and re-install (with no weird clicking noises this time).  Not sure why it started working--WOL would have no effect, just wanted it on for other reasons.  Thanks!